# How to write select Onchange event in jsp to forward request to spring mvc controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

How to write select Onchange event in JSP to forward request to Spring MVC controller?

Answer (score 0):

In the jsp,on the combobox add the onchange event shown below

```
  <spring:form method="POST" modelAttribute="something"> 
          <spring:select path="code"  onchange="this.form.submit();" >
          .......<spring:option>...</spring:option>

           </spring:select>

    </spring:form>
```